# Code Skip Command/Code Loop Command

Tags: goto

I'm not sure if there is already a command like this existing, but what about a command like that in a code language:

```
do this 
do that 

<point2>

if (something){
   GOTO ('point1')
}
do this 
do that 

<point1>

do this 
do that

if (something){
   go to ('point2')
}
```

a command which just leads the program to a point forward or backward in the code

i know you can do this with if clauses and functions and have the same effect

otherwise with this command you can portray code in blocks:

```
 _____________ <-----
| start motor |     | Go to command
| if failure  -------
|_____________|
   |
   |
   \/
  Drive
```

My questions:

do we need this command? , is it useful in languages like java or php or else? and why is it unset in java? Could it be upgraded or made better and how? is it enough for not using loops anymore? Or has a goto command a major downside? Maybe in compiling or so its performance is bad...      ----why dont i use it or find it in any tutorial when it could be a standard command like loops...   why????

I'm thankful for a nice discussion about this command and for not writing how many grammar mistakes I made ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"a command which just leads the program to a point forward or backward in the code" <-- it is called GOTO command. Different programming language may implement it differently.

"nice discussion about this command" <--- After your research, mind sharing which part of the reading materials/reference/code that you don't understand or can't be execute? A sample code and screenshot may help too.. (:

Comment: My question is rather: do we need this command? , is it useful in languages like java or php or else? and why is it unset in java? Could it be upgraded or made better and how? is it enough for not using loops anymore? Or has a goto command a major downside? Maybe in compiling or so its performance is bad...

Comment: I see... in structured programming methodolgy of writing/creating programs you don't need it. But in special case Eg. software testing/creating virus/creating antivirus/investigating software abnormal behaviour, GOTO is one of the great tool to be used. |  IMHO : in the current age.. defenitely still need it.. for advanced users especially.  (:

Comment: "a goto command a major downside?" <-- when there is error/maintenance it'll VERY hard to debug/trace.

Comment: Technically : if you are working with assembly language or BASIC.. it is everywhere. In C language.. somewhere.. But for other high level language, nowhere/hidden/disabled. Since all the practical situation that need GOTO before can be implemented by for/if/while loop.  || Ethically : It is a very unstructured/messy programming style. Not recommended to be taught to new learners. This kind of implementation is not technically impossible, it just that structured code are preferred for clarity and long term code sustenance.